# Should I Use a Separate UIViewController for a Popup Menu?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

A rather theoretical or abstract question...

I have a view controller  (let's call it viewControllerA) with a view (obviously). While the view is displayed, should the user press a specific button a popup menu will appear (think of a grid of buttons). The user can press a button in the popup menu to transition to another view (controlled by another view controller).

Should I have a separate view controller to handle/manage the popup menu or should I "simply" implement the popup menu as a view which is controlled by the same view controller (i.e. viewControllerA)?

Reasons for and against each approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Should I have a separate view controller to handle/manage the popup menu?**

I believe, this is the better option. You can create a container view on storyboard which will have a separate controller which is much easier to work with, then a huge file with different views.

What you will gain:

1. Nicely structured files with a single responsibility
2. Easier to test and adjust both elements

**Should I "simply" implement the popup menu as a view which is controlled by the same view controller?**

There are no advantages in this approach as it looks to me.
In this case you will:

1. Violate a [single responsibility principle](https://github.com/ochococo/OOD-Principles-In-Swift#-the-single-responsibility-principle).
2. "simply" - will mean that you will have 2 different views with their lifecycles managed in one controller (simply becomes harder)
3. most probably it will be Massive View Controller

If you don't use any particular architecture pattern, maybe you should take a look [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use UIViewController as a Popup.

**Step1**: Take a new UIViewController on the storyboard and create a class associated with it.

**Step 2**: You said that after clicking on the button that Popup has to show, then take a button on the first ViewController and write below code

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PopupViewController *popupVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popId"];

BIZPopupViewController *popupViewController = [[BIZPopupViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popupVC contentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];

[self presentViewController:popupViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

It will show PopupViewController as a popup view in your view.

[Here is the link for BIZpopViewController](https://github.com/bizibizi/BIZPopupView) copy the class into your project, it will work.